# what is the meaning of line n= n and int(n) in python

Tags: python

```
def get(self){
   n=self.get.request(n,0)
   n=n and int(n)
   self.render(fizzbuzz.html,n=n)
}
```

In this what is the meaning of line `n=n and int(n)`
this is lines of codes are took from udacity cs253 course. and yes can u also suggest me any similar course but an updated because cs 253 is way to old...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `and` operator returns the value of the first "falsey" value it sees, or the second value if both are true. So you have:

```
>>> 0 and False
0
>>> False and 0
False
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> -2 and 0
0
>>> 5 and 3
3
```

In your case, you have `n and int(n)`. If `n` or `int(n)` is zero, this will return 0. If both are nonzero, it will return `int(n)`.

It's worth remarking that (a) this code is unnecessarily confusing, and (b) it could be simplified just by using `int(n)`; if `n` is zero, then `int(n)` is zero, so there's no point in checking `n` first.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

```
n = n and int(n)
```

will first evaluate `n`. If its value is 0, or `""`, or `False` (or a number of [other "falsy" values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)) then `n` will be unchanged. If `n` is anything else, then `int(n)` will be called to convert it to an integer and the result will be assigned to `n`.

This is a rather unusual thing to write and it's not clear from the code you posted why the author didn't simply write `n = int(n)`.